# Data not stored to db as requested in a facebook graph app

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, web, file-get-contents

I am trying to save data from the facebook graph to my db.  I am not sure if my bug is in the facebook part or the php part.

When I run the code nothing happens on the screen.  No error message and no forwarding to other location (via header) and no data is saved to the db.

Attached is the code:

```
if ($cookie) 
{
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$cookie['access_token']),true);

        if ($user)
        {
        // Connect to database
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
        mysql_select_db('xxxxx');
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (xxxx, xxxx) VALUES ('".$user['data']['id']."', '"$user['data']['name']."');");
        if ($result)
        {
        // If User successfully stored - redirect to update or post on Facebook wall 
        header("Location: http://xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx.php"); 
                exit;
                }
                else
                {
                // If Error in storing
                echo '$result is empty';
                }
        }   
        else 
        {
        // If error in parsing
        echo '$user is empty';
        }
}
else 
{
// If error in authentication status
echo '$cookie is empty';
}
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/me won't work with file get contents. You'll need to specify an Id of a facebook user/page to get the content.

Comment: are you sure?  I replaced the "me" with $cookie['uid'] and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you get no output, it probably means your script is crashing early on.  Are you using a PHP version that supports json_decode?  That would be my first check.  Otherwise, try putting this at the very top of your script and see if you get any clues:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```